# How to get document object from JavaScript function exported to content?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon-sdk

I have trying to improve [signTextJS](https://github.com/mozkeeler/signTextJS/) Firefox add-on. This add-on exports function to content using Components.utils.exportFunction. The problem is that for correct processing I need to get character set of document that called my function. The function had one input parameter - test to be signed and I can't add more, because this is reimplementation of old API.

Is there direct way to get calling document object? I have access to DOMWindow, and therefore document when function is registered, but I need it when it is called from page script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this can be achieved easy using bind on registration and setting document object as additional parameter of implementing function. Here is the link to relevant commit from author of the extension for anyone interested in it - https://github.com/mozkeeler/signTextJS/commit/844f144bb623f1633a70c9d68ea00e4cbb63375b.